# ACCESS 2007 - how can I open select window dialog from VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access-2007

I just converted ACCESS 2000 to ACCESS 2007 application.
How do I access to the switch windows - "select window" dialog, how can I open this dialog from VBA

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

`DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdMoreWindows`